# Нужна ли запятая после слова "например" в присоединительной конструкции?

Tags: пунктуация

*Государственные пенсионные фонды, собирающие, например в США, ежегодно сотни миллиардов долларов, вкладывают их в облигации министерства финансов.*

В этом предложении после слова "например" нужна запятая? Или она не ставится по причине того, что перед нами присоединительная конструкция?

Comment: Это не присоединительная конструкция, а пояснительный оборот. Если вводное слово стоит в начале оборота, оно не отделяется запятой

Answer (score 0):

Да нет же, это смысловая запятая! Что там автор имел в виду...

Если нам хотят подчеркнуть, что информация (конкретика о ежегодных сотнях миллиардов долларов, вкладываемых в облигации министерства финансов) именно по США, то и запятая на месте (после США).

Если запятую поставить после "например", то останутся - в привязке к США - только это сотни млрд, а вся прочая информация становится ничейной, общей:

*Государственные пенсионные фонды, собирающие ежегодно сотни миллиардов долларов, вкладывают их в облигации министерства финансов.*